# Sql queries in Django

Tags: sql, django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

here is my sql query

```
SELECT id, name, address, city, state_province, country, website
FROM books_publisher
WHERE name LIKE '%press' and city LIKE '%myn';
```

as you can see on the above code i have used `and` for multiple `like` how to do the same thing in Django? i tried this but did not work

```
Mplaces.objects.filter(name__startswith='press' and city__startswith=myn)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
Mplaces.objects.filter(name__endswith='press', city__endswith=myn)
```

here ,(comma) means 'and' and | means 'or'

Answer (score 0):

```
Mplaces.objects.filter(name__endswith='press', city__endswith='myn')
```

SQL equivalent:

```
SELECT ... WHERE name LIKE "%press" and city LIKE "%myn";
```